# FunctionalDependencies does not unify on uniquely identified type

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies, type-families

Here is the definition for `MonadState`, but question applies to any such class with `FunctionalDependencies`:

```hs
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
...
```

Consider I have data type that uses `s` as the type argument and a type class that works works with it:

```hs
data StateType s = StateType

class MonadState s m => FunDeps s m a where
  workWithStateType :: a -> StateType s -> m ()
```

I can happily create an instance  for this class which compiles and works as expected:

```hs
instance (MonadIO m, MonadState s m) => FunDeps s m (IORef (StateType s)) where
  workWithStateType ref a = liftIO $ writeIORef ref a
```

But it feels to me that `s` in `FunDeps` class is redundant and I could define a class like so:

```hs
class FunDepsProblem m a where
  workWithStateTypeNoCompile :: MonadState s m => a -> StateType s -> m ()

instance (MonadIO m, MonadState s m) => FunDepsProblem m (IORef (StateType s)) where
  ...
```

The problem is when I try to implement it:

```
instance (MonadIO m, MonadState s m) => FunDepsProblem m (IORef (StateType s)) where
  workWithStateTypeNoCompile ref a = liftIO $ writeIORef ref a
```

I get a compilation error that tells me that it can't unify the state token `s` in the instance head and in the function:

```
fun-deps.hs:18:62: error: …
    • Couldn't match type ‘s1’ with ‘s’
      ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          workWithStateTypeNoCompile :: forall s1.
                                        MonadState s1 m =>
                                        IORef (StateType s) -> StateType s1 -> m ()
        at /path/to/fun-deps.hs:18:3-28
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at /path/to/fun-deps.hs:17:10-78
      Expected type: StateType s
        Actual type: StateType s1
    • In the second argument of ‘writeIORef’, namely ‘a’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘writeIORef ref a’
      In the expression: liftIO $ writeIORef ref a
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: StateType s1
          (bound at /path/to/fun-deps.hs:18:34)
        ref :: IORef (StateType s)
          (bound at /path/to/fun-deps.hs:18:30)
        workWithStateTypeNoCompile :: IORef (StateType s)
                                      -> StateType s1 -> m ()
          (bound at /path/to/fun-deps.hs:18:3)
   |
Compilation failed.
```

I understand that when it is defined in such form there is an implicit `forall` there:

```
  workWithStateTypeNoCompile :: forall s m a . MonadState s m => a -> StateType s -> m ()
```

so technically it should work for every `s`, and it would totally make sense with absence of `FunctionalDependencies`, but `s` is known when `m` is known, so that is the part that I don't get.

In other words the monad `m` is unified to be the same in the class head and in the function, so  it should uniquely identify the state type `s` both in instance head and in the function type. So my question is how come it is not being unified? Is there a theoretical reason for this or is it simply not implemented in ghc?

In fact, if I rewrite `MonadState` into a conceptually the same functionality, but using `TypeFamilies` instead of `FunctionalDependencies` the problem seem to go away:

```hs
class Monad m => MonadStateFamily m where
  type StateToken m :: *

class Family m a where
  familyStateType :: MonadStateFamily m => a -> StateType (StateToken m) -> m ()

instance (MonadIO m, MonadStateFamily m, s ~ StateToken m) => Family m (IORef (StateType s)) where
  familyStateType ref a = liftIO $ writeIORef ref a
```

Comment: Thought: What happens when you enable -XScopedTypeVariables and give `workWithStateTypeNoCompile` a signature which explicitly unifies the variables?

Comment: @bradrn It was worth a try, but no luck, same error.

Comment: I believe that GHC just doesn't treat `FunctionalDependencies` as "functions." That is, there is no new type axiom associated with it. Even if you know `class C a b | a -> b; instance C A B; instance C A C`, there is no proof that `B ~ C`. Functional dependencies is really "just inference": if there is a want for `instance C A _b` with `_b` unknown, then an instance can be picked (incoherently) to set `_b` to a type, and this is justified by the restrictions on instance writing (that `B` and `C` must be the same anyway), but that equality is not internalized as a rule in the system itself.

Comment: @HTNW But FunDeps ensure that such instances cannot coexist: `instance C A B; instance C A C`. Such instance is also illegal: `instance C A _b` and no extension can let you pick it incoherently. So I don't quite follow your argument

Comment: That's a true property of the type system of Haskell, but inside the type system of Haskell there simply isn't a way to prove that. E.g. `excl :: Either a (a -> Void)` is also not possible to write in (total) Haskell, yet there is no `anticlassical :: (forall a. Either a (a -> Void)) -> Void` either. That is, some things are not true but also not false. In this case, it is true that `B` and `C` would have to be the same for the instances to go through, but it is not true that that is provable inside Haskell.

Comment: @HTNW So what you are saying is that it is simply not implemented in ghc, but as far as Haskell is concerned it could work the way I describe it in the question if some work were to be done in improving Haskell type system. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: There might be a reason why it's not implemented. Perhaps adding it would be safe. Make an issue against GHC and ask about it.

Comment: @HTNW Thank you. Creating a GHC issue was my next step. I'll give it a couple more days, see if anyone comes in and says that this idea is stupid and it will never work neither in practice nor in theory ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known limitation of `FunctionalDependencies`. I dug up a Haskell-cafe [message by Manuel Chakravarty](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-February/055890.html) from over a decade ago which mentions that `FunctionalDependencies` don't work with existential types and provided a very concise and clear example:

```hs
class F a r | a -> r
instance F Bool Int

data T a = forall b. F a b => MkT b

add :: T Bool -> T Bool -> T Bool
add (MkT x) (MkT y) = MkT (x + y)
```

Example above produces the compiler error which says that it can't unify on the uniquely identified type, essentially the title of the question.

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘b1’
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor: MkT :: forall a b. F a b => b -> T a,
        in an equation for ‘add’
```

This is the compilation error from the question, which looks very similar to the one above.

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘s1’ with ‘s’
      ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          workWithStateTypeNoCompile :: forall s1.
                                        MonadState s1 m =>
                                        IORef (StateType s) -> StateType s1 -> m ()
```

I suspect that exactly the same concepts are at play here, because of the `forall` on the `workWithStateTypeNoCompile`, the type variable `s1` in the error is the existential.

In any case not all is lost and there is a decent workaround for the problem I was having. In particular removal of the `s` from the class instance head is necessary, which can be achieved with a `newtype`:

```hs
class FunDepsWorks m a where
  workWithStateTypeCompile :: MonadState s m => a s -> StateType s -> m ()

newtype StateTypeRef s = StateTypeRef (IORef (StateType s))

instance MonadIO m => FunDepsWorks m StateTypeRef where
  workWithStateTypeCompile (StateTypeRef ref) a = liftIO $ writeIORef ref a
```

Note that the `a` is now a type variable with arity one and is applied to `s`.

Thanks to Ben Gamari for compiling [tf vs fd](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/tf-vs-fd) wiki page, otherwise I would have never found that example with existential types.